# already vs already been

Tags: grammar

1. She needs to realize that the rose-colored glasses have **already** broken.
2. She needs to realize that the rose-colored glasses have **already been** broken.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

As the glasses are unlikely to have broken themselves, we need the passive voice, *are [already] broken*, or present perfect passive, *have [already] been broken*.

> She needs to realize that the rose-colored glasses have already been broken.